# adding CKEditor to my html/php page

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, editor

I have a forum ish site that I am building. Now I want the CKEditor to be my reaction block so I can make text **bold** and *emphasized* but the problem is I am making my website in a PDO, Now I downloaded the plug-in but I am not really sure how to go on from there.

I tried this code:

```
<div class="box box-info">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title">CK Editor <small>Advanced and full of features</small></h3>
        <!-- tools box -->
        <div class="pull-right box-tools">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!-- /. tools -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body pad">
        <form>
            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                                            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.box -->

<script>
    $(function () {
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
        // instance, using default configuration.
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        //bootstrap WYSIHTML5 - text editor
        $(".textarea").wysihtml5();
    });
</script>
```

The plug-in is in a map with all my plug-ins I am using.

**How it looks like now**

[image]

Comment: what was the exact problem?

Comment: As you can see in the img I posted it is not showing the functions to make it bold ect, that is what I want. I want to be abble to make text bold @KamleshSolanki

Comment: `$(".textarea")` will not select anything because the class `.textarea` was not used in the code you pasted.

Comment: Did you include the script tags to load jQuery and CKEditor? In [the examples](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html#adding-ckeditor-to-your-page) they don't have the wrapping function `$(function() {...`

Comment: Check browser console if there is no error. If there are some errors, those might be helpful what happen there. Please be also sure that CKEditor library is loaded before `CKEDITOR.replace` is run on page.